# Substitution on a Temperature Problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, heat-equation, sturm-liouville

Given real parameters $A,B,C$ consider the temperature problem with non-homogeneous boundary conditions:

$$u_t=ku_{xx},   \;\;\;   u=u(x,t), \;\;\;0\leq x\leq \pi,\;\;\; t,k> 0$$
$$u_x(0,t)=u(0,t)+A$$
$$u_x(\pi,t)=u(\pi,t)+B$$
$$u(x,0)=Cx$$

I am tasked to use a substitution $u(x,t)=U(x,t)+\Phi(x)$ to reduce it to the temperature problem:

$$u_t=ku_{xx},   \;\;\;   u=u(x,t), \;\;\;0\leq x\leq \pi,\;\;\; t,k> 0$$
$$u_x(0,t)=u(0,t)$$
$$u_x(\pi,t)=u(\pi,t)$$
$$u(x,0)=f(x)\in C^0([0,\pi])$$

Furthermore I am to indicate new initial temperatures F(x) in the homogeneous problem about U(x,t).

What is this substitution? I know that the second temperature problem has its solution, in the form of an infinite series, as $$u(x,t)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_ny_n(x)T_n(t)$$
but I do not know what the constants $c_n$ are, nor do I know the functions $y, T$ (I am currently attempting to solve this problem, I posted another question on it). Will I have to use this infinite series solution to determine the substitution? Will I need it to determine F(x) in the homogenous problem about U(x,t)? I'm not even 100% sure what "the homogeneous problem about U(x,t)" is. I would love clarification on any of these issues, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a linear function $\Phi(x)=Dx+E$. Here is what you need from this function:
$$
\Phi_x(0)=u_x(0,t)-U_x(0,t)=u(0,t)+A-U(0,t)=u(0,t)+A-u(0,t)+\Phi(0)=\Phi(0)+A
$$
and
$$
\Phi_x(\pi)=u_x(\pi,t)-U_x(\pi,t)=u(\pi,t)+B-U(\pi,t)=u(\pi,t)+B-u(\pi,t)+\Phi(\pi)=\Phi(\pi)+B
$$
So you get a system
$$
D=A+E;\qquad D=D\pi+E+B
$$
where you can easily find $D$ and $E$ in terms of $A$ and $B$.

The initial condition becomes $U(x,0)=(C+D)x+E$.

Comment: I get most of the work up to $U(x,0)=(C+D)x+E$. Where did this come from? Furthermore I obtain $D=\frac{A-B}{\pi}, E=\frac{A(1-\pi)-B}{\pi}$, which would make $U(x,0)=\left( C+\frac{A-B}{\pi}\right)x+\frac{A(1-\pi)-B}{\pi}$. Also, in what sense is this temperature problem "reduced" to the second temperature problem? Where does f(x) fit into this? How can Cx be "reduced" to f(x), when f(x) is more general than Cx? Is it really just saying we need U(x,0) to be in terms of x (which of course, it is)?

Comment: @RungSoup The values you found seem to be correct. The problem is reduced in the sense that you solve a simpler problem (a homogeneous one) for U using the technique of separation of variables and then obtain the solution of the original one by just adding the specific function $\Phi$. The initial data just change to something else, probably the notation is not very fortunate. The fact that your specific initial data have the form u(x,0)=Cx is irrelevant here.

Answer (score 0):

If $u$ is a solution of $u_t=u_{xx}$, then so is $v(x,t)=u(x,t)+R+Sx$, for any constants $R,S$. This is because $(R+Sx)_t=0=(R+Sx)_{xx}$. This gives you a little flexibility to change your equation in $u$ to an equation in $v$ that has homogeneous endpoint conditions, which can then be solved using separation of variables. The new problem becomes
$$
        v_t = v_{xx},\\ v_x(0,t)=u_{x}(0,t)+S=(u(0,t)+A)+S=v(0,t)-R+S \\
        v_{x}(\pi,t)=u_x(\pi,t)+S=u(\pi,t)+B+S=v(\pi,t)-R+S+B \\
        v(x,0)=u(x,0)+R+Sx=Cx+R+Sx=(C+S)x+R.
$$